# I'm unable to get data from db when i click on listeview item

Tags: android

I couldn't get corresponds data from list view's item.
here i am using sms and email templates.  when i click on sms or any email listviews item then it will open in edit text form db and then  could update data and then store. corresponding with email or sms .i create fields into db for email and sms template such as
id, template_name, message, template_code(0,1) i.e. specifies which on i'm using either sms or email.
here is three activity ManageEmailTemplate, ManageSmsTemplate that intents to next activity i.e. SMSTemplateEdit

ManageEmailTemplate.java

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.manage_email_template);

        //-------------------------
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open();

        mQuery = "Select " +
                       Constants.KEY_ID_GREET + "," +
                       Constants.GREETING_NAME + "," +
                       Constants.GREETING_MESSAGE+ "," +
                       Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET  +
                       " from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_GREETINGS +
                       " where " + Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET + " = " + Constants.EMAIL_CODE;

        c = dba.getResults( mQuery );
        startManagingCursor(c); 

        String[] resultColumns;

        if( c != null && c.moveToFirst()){      

        }

        int[] textviews = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        resultColumns = new String[] { Constants.GREETING_NAME};

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, resultColumns, textviews);

        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        //dba.close();

        //-------------------------

        // Create Email Templates
        //setup Create Email Templates Listener       
        Button createEmailTemplatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_email_template_button);
            createEmailTemplatesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    showCreateEmailTemplate();
                }
        });  


    }

    private void showCreateEmailTemplate(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateNewTemplate.class);
        i.putExtra("template_type","email");
        //startActivity(i);

        startActivityForResult(i, mRequestCode);
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id)
    {

        super.onItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

     final Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);

     String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( Constants.GREETING_NAME ));
    final int template_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex( Constants.KEY_ID_GREET ));
     temp_id=String.valueOf(template_id);


     goForEdit();
     //confirm
Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name :"+name+"  id : " +template_id , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();    
     }

    public void goForEdit(){
        Intent launchSMSTempEdit = new Intent(
                ManageEmailTemplate.this,
                            EmailSMSTempEdit.class);

launchSMSTempEdit.getExtras().get("selection"));
    //        startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);

                //  Toast.makeText(this, temp_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                  startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);

                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                     //now get Editor
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                     //put your value
                     editor.putString("Temp_id", temp_id);
                     editor.putString("template_type", "email");
                     //commits your edits
                     editor.commit();   

                     startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);

    }

}


ManageSMSTemplate.java


public class ManageSMSTemplate extends
        ActionBarListActivity {

    private MyDB dba;

    private Cursor c;
    String temp_id;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    private int mRequestCode = 0000;
ListView lst;
    private String mQuery;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        lst =(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.manage_sms_template);

        // -------------------------
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open();

        mQuery = "Select " + Constants.KEY_ID_GREET + ","
                + Constants.GREETING_NAME + ","
                + Constants.GREETING_MESSAGE + ","
                + Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET + " from "
                + Constants.TABLE_NAME_GREETINGS
                + " where " + Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET
                + " = " + Constants.SMS_CODE;

        c = dba.getResults(mQuery);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] resultColumns;

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

        }

        int[] textviews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        resultColumns = new String[] { Constants.GREETING_NAME };
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c,
                resultColumns, textviews);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // -------------------------

        // Create sms Templates
        // setup Create SMS Templates Listener
        Button createSMSTemplatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_sms_template_button);
        createSMSTemplatesButton
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {

                        showCreateSMSTemplate();
                    }
                });

    }

    private void showCreateSMSTemplate()
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateNewTemplate.class);
        i.putExtra("template_type", "sms");
        startActivityForResult(i, mRequestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
            int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,
                data);

        Log.v("Crash",
                "Returned from template creation in SMStemplate Manager");

        if (mAdapter == null)
            Log.d("Crash", "SMS-Manager - mAdapter is NULL");
        else
            Log.d("Crash",
                    "SMS-Manager - mAdapter is NOT Null");

        if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (mAdapter.getCursor() != null)
                    mAdapter.getCursor().requery();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {

        dba.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id)
    {

        super.onItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

        final Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter
                .getItem(position);

        String name = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Constants.GREETING_NAME));
        final int template_id = c.getInt(c
                .getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID_GREET));
         temp_id=String.valueOf(template_id);

goForEdit();


         // confirm
Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name :"+name+"  id : " +template_id , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }
    public void goForEdit(){
        Intent launchSMSTempEdit = new Intent(
                ManageSMSTemplate.this,
                            EmailSMSTempEdit.class);

    //  Intent i = new Intent(ManageSMSTemplate.this, SMSTempEdit.class);
        //i.putExtra("KeyId", temp_id.toString());
         //  startActivity(i);

         //  launchSMSTempEdit.putExtra("selection", temp_id.toString());
       //     Log.d("*** OUTBOUND INTENT: ", "" + launchSMSTempEdit.getExtras().get("selection"));
    //        startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);

                //  Toast.makeText(this, temp_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                  startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);

                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                     //now get Editor
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                     //put your value
                     editor.putString("userName", temp_id);
                     editor.putString("template_type", "sms");
                     //commits your edits
                     editor.commit();   

                     startActivity(launchSMSTempEdit);

    }


}


EmailSMSTempEdit.java

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_template);

       // sms_key_id=getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
 //       String sms_key_id;    
  //      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   //         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     //       if(extras == null) {
       //       sms_key_id= null;
         //   } else {
      //        sms_key_id= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
        //    }
      //  } else {
        //  sms_key_id= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
      //  }
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sms_key_id = sharedPref.getString("userName", "Not Available");
        mTemplateType=sharedPref.getString("template_type", "Not Available");
        Toast.makeText(this, mTemplateType, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open() ;

        //array to hold values to show in spinner 
        nameTypeArr = new String[]{getString(R.string.insert_name_prompt), 
                                   getString(R.string.first_name), 
                                   getString(R.string.last_name)};

        //get views from xml
        mNameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.template_name_box);        
        mSubjectBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.template_subject_box);        
        mMessageBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.template_message_box);        
        mInsertNameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.insert_name_here_spinner);

        //create adapter for the spinner and set it
        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter1= 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameTypeArr);

        mAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        mInsertNameSpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter1);

        //listener for the spinner
        mInsertNameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                        View view, int pos, long id) { 

                //if the spinner has just been created, ignore this call to onItemSelected
                if(spinnerBeingCreated == true){
                    spinnerBeingCreated = false;
                    return;
                }
                //what item did the user click in spinner
                String typeOfName = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                //based on user choice, insert corresponding placeholder in text
                if(typeOfName.equals( getString(R.string.first_name) )){
                    insertAtCurrentLocation( getString(R.string.first_name_placeholder) );
                }else if(typeOfName.equals( getString(R.string.last_name) )){
                    insertAtCurrentLocation( getString(R.string.last_name_placeholder) );
                }
                //reset the spinner item selection back to first one
                mInsertNameSpinner.setSelection(0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });


        //if its a template for sms, hide the subject line
        LinearLayout subjectarea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.template_subject_box_container);

        if(mTemplateType.equals("sms")){
            subjectarea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if(mTemplateType.equals("email")){
            subjectarea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        fillData(sms_key_id);

        //Save the template
        //setup Save Template Listener       
        Button saveTemplateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_template_button);
        saveTemplateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
       //       saveTemplate();

        updateTemplate(sms_key_id);
            }
        });

        //Cancel
        //Cancel Listener       
        Button cancelTemplateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_template_button);
        cancelTemplateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

public void fillData(String sms_key_id) {
    Toast.makeText(EmailSMSTempEdit.this, sms_key_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    dba.open();
        String queryStr = 
               "Select " +
                     "*" + " from " +  
                Constants.TABLE_NAME_GREETINGS + 
                " where "+  Constants.KEY_ID_GREET+"=" + sms_key_id ;


        //Toast.makeText(this, queryStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

           c = dba.getResults(queryStr);
            startManagingCursor(c);

            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do{

                    mNameBox.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.GREETING_NAME)));
                    mMessageBox.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.GREETING_MESSAGE)));

            //      System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID_GREET)));
        //          System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.GREETING_NAME)));
            //      System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.GREETING_MESSAGE)));
            //      System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET)));
                } while(c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

    public void updateTemplate(String sms_key_id){

        String subject = mSubjectBox.getText().toString();
        String name = mNameBox.getText().toString();
        String message = mMessageBox.getText().toString();
dba.open();     
        //if name is null or empty, don't save
        if(name == null || name.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.empty_template_name_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //whether its sms or email, requied fro db query
        int messageTypeCode = -1;   //for sms, it is 0. For email it is 1

        if(mTemplateType.equals("email")){
            message = subject + subjectMessageDelimiter + message;  //|~| is the delimiter
            messageTypeCode = Constants.EMAIL_CODE;
        } else if(mTemplateType.equals("sms")){
            messageTypeCode = Constants.SMS_CODE;
        }

    String  Stmt = "update  " + 
                Constants.TABLE_NAME_GREETINGS +
                " set "+
                Constants.GREETING_NAME+"='"+name + "',"+
                Constants.GREETING_MESSAGE+"='"+message + "'," +
                Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET+"='"+messageTypeCode +"'" +
                " where "+ Constants.KEY_ID_GREET+"=" + sms_key_id ;




    dba.execute(Stmt);

    dba.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully updated Template: " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    //finish the activity
//  setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    finish();



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        //dba.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //insert at currnet cursor location in subject or message field
    private void insertAtCurrentLocation(String str){

        int start, end;

        if(mMessageBox.hasFocus()){
            start = mMessageBox.getSelectionStart();
            end = mMessageBox.getSelectionEnd();
            mMessageBox.getText().replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end),
                                            str, 0, str.length());
        } else if(mSubjectBox.hasFocus()){
            start = mSubjectBox.getSelectionStart();
            end = mSubjectBox.getSelectionEnd();
            mSubjectBox.getText().replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end),
                                            str, 0, str.length());
        }

    }

    private boolean alreadyExists(String templateName){

        int type_code = -1;

        if(mTemplateType.equals("sms")){
            type_code = Constants.SMS_CODE;
        } else if(mTemplateType.equals("email")){
            type_code = Constants.EMAIL_CODE;
        }

        String query = "Select * from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_GREETINGS 
                + " where " + Constants.GREETING_NAME + " = '" + templateName 
                + "' AND " +  Constants.KEY_ID_SETUP_GREET + "=" + type_code;

        Cursor c = null;
        Boolean exists = false;

        dba.open();

        try {
            c = dba.getResults( query );
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    exists = (c.getCount() > 0);

                } else {
                    exists = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CreateNewTemplate", "Error while checking if name already exists. Details: "+e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
            dba.close();
        }
        return exists;
    }

}
```

Comment: show onClick Item method of ListView code

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: in `onItemClick` call `c.moveToPosition`

Comment: there are two onItemClick where i have to call c.moveToPosition @ pslink

Comment: in both, you have to `moveToPosition` in both cases

Answer (score 0):

move your cursor to the position of the list view item that you have clicked and then fetch the data from db using that cursor. Below is a small snippet:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(cursor!=null){
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                //do your stuff here....
                cursor.close();


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: what `Cursor`? i bet the OP uses `ArrayAdapter` not `[Simple]CursorAdapter`, 99% folks here use `ArrayAdapter`  / `BaseAdapter` when dealing with sqlite db, i cannot understand why...

Comment: the modular way to show data from the db is by using CursorAdapter. I have just given a small snippet above which uses cursor to tell the op that he can use it to get the data of the list item that has been clicked.

Comment: got it ur point man but in my case there is different one @KaveeshKanwalhttp        [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367433/im-unable-to-get-data-from-db-when-i-click-on-listeview-item?noredirect=1#comment52606839_32367433

Comment: if you are maintaining different tables then do it in both, if not then just one cursor is enough to the get the data from the desired row

Comment: ok fine.. when i click on sms list view that  edited fine but in case of email it  overrides sms values into email listview items data

Comment: use a different cursor for your email click. Always make cursor have local scope and remember to close it in the end.